# could not find __debug_line section in binary when runnig dlv debug test.go

Tags: debugging, go

Using macOS, installed dlv via `brew install go-delve/delve/delve`

then try to debug a program in test.go like this: `dlv debug test.go`

then got this error:

`could not launch process: could not find __debug_line section in binary`

Any suggestion?

---

updated on 9/4

I uninstalled the brew dlv and install like below, it still not work.

`localhost:dlv lua$ go get github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv
localhost:dlv lua$ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv
localhost:dlv lua$ go build 
localhost:dlv lua$ go install
localhost:dlv lua$ pwd
/Users/lua/go/src/github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv
localhost:dlv lua$ dlv
-bash: /usr/local/bin/dlv: No such file or directory
localhost:dlv lua$`

Comment: which version of go?

Comment: go1.10.3 darwin/amd64

Comment: add this to your path variable and check `/Users/lua/go/bin`

Comment: ok, that works, thanks.  emm..., we still can't get rid of $PATH, thought it was different from go...

Answer (score 0):

You can install it from the source code instead of using brew.

```
go get github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv
go build 
go install
```

This should fix this issue.

Comment: Yes uninstall the previous binary, then install the new one using the above commands.

Comment: that does not work either..., i put the cmd line output in the  original question description